# Bootstrap range slider onSlideStop not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, range, onchange

I'm trying to trigger an event from my range slider (bootstrap). Here's the code for the slider:

```
<input type="text" onSlideStop="alert(this.value);" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[1,2]" id="sl2">
```

Now, I am able to trigger an event from JS, but since I'm going to have quite a bit of sliders on my page, I would like to trigger it from the slider itself.

Here's the code that does work on JS:

```
$('#sl2').slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
alert($('#sl2').data('slider').getValue());
});
```

JS fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/hw1aer2f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, jQueryUI interfered with the bootstrap slider script. I solved it by simply loading jQueryUI after bootstrap slider.